# escape the double quotes using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

How to escape the double quotes using XSLT:

My xls file converting xml file into csv file.

my xml node is as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<TRADING_TITLE><TITLE>SBU</TITLE><DESCRIPTION><![CDATA[Simply Be Inquiries]]></DESCRIPTION><REGISTERED><NAME><![CDATA[Speciality Home Shopping (US) Limited]]></NAME><ADDRESS1><![CDATA[Griffin House]]></ADDRESS1><ADDRESS2><![CDATA[40 Lever Street]]></ADDRESS2><ADDRESS3><![CDATA[Manchester]]></ADDRESS3><ADDRESS4><![CDATA[United Kingdom]]></ADDRESS4><ADDRESS5><![CDATA[M60  6ES]]></ADDRESS5></REGISTERED><WEB_ADDRESS>www.simplybe.com</WEB_ADDRESS><COMPANY_NUMBER>03941468</COMPANY_NUMBER><ENQUIRY_DAYS_PER_WEEK>7</ENQUIRY_DAYS_PER_WEEK><ENQUIRY_TEL_NO>18774074675</ENQUIRY_TEL_NO><ORDER_TEL_NO>18774074675</ORDER_TEL_NO><ORDERLINETIMES><WEEKDAY_OPEN>8am</WEEKDAY_OPEN><WEEKDAY_CLOSE>11pm</WEEKDAY_CLOSE><SATURDAY_OPEN>8am</SATURDAY_OPEN><SATURDAY_CLOSE>11pm</SATURDAY_CLOSE><SUNDAY_OPEN>8am</SUNDAY_OPEN><SUNDAY_CLOSE>11pm</SUNDAY_CLOSE></ORDERLINETIMES><ENQUIRYLINETIMES><WEEKDAY_OPEN>8am</WEEKDAY_OPEN><WEEKDAY_CLOSE>11pm</WEEKDAY_CLOSE><SATURDAY_OPEN>8am</SATURDAY_OPEN><SATURDAY_CLOSE>11pm</SATURDAY_CLOSE><SUNDAY_OPEN>8am</SUNDAY_OPEN><SUNDAY_CLOSE>11pm</SUNDAY_CLOSE></ENQUIRYLINETIMES><CORRESPONDENCE><NAME><![CDATA[Simply Be Inquiries]]></NAME><ADDRESS1><![CDATA[777 South State Road 7]]></ADDRESS1><ADDRESS2><![CDATA[Margate, Florida 33068]]></ADDRESS2><ADDRESS3/><ADDRESS4/><ADDRESS5/></CORRESPONDENCE><TRADING_AS_INDICATOR>Y</TRADING_AS_INDICATOR><REGISTERED_NUMBER>03941468</REGISTERED_NUMBER><BRAND_LOGO_NUMBER>DAL90</BRAND_LOGO_NUMBER><FSA_TEXT><![CDATA["Simply Be" is a trading name of Speciality Home Shopping (US) Limited, registered in England with Co No. 03941468 and registered office at Griffin House, 40 Lever Street, Manchester UK M60 6ES]]></FSA_TEXT></TRADING_TITLE>
```

I want to replace " with "" in whole XML file.Please help.

My xls file is as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <!--  Now process each notification detail -->
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::TRADING_TITLE">

            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>A,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="TITLE != ''">
                    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"></xsl:value-of>
                    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                    &comma;
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"></xsl:value-of>
                    &comma;
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>       

            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="REGISTERED/NAME"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>  
            <xsl:value-of select="REGISTERED/ADDRESS1"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="REGISTERED/ADDRESS2"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma; 
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="REGISTERED/ADDRESS3"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="REGISTERED/ADDRESS4"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="REGISTERED/ADDRESS5"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="WEB_ADDRESS"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="COMPANY_NUMBER"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ENQUIRY_DAYS_PER_WEEK"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ENQUIRY_TEL_NO"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ORDER_TEL_NO"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ORDERLINETIMES/WEEKDAY_OPEN"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ORDERLINETIMES/WEEKDAY_CLOSE"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ORDERLINETIMES/SATURDAY_OPEN"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ORDERLINETIMES/SATURDAY_CLOSE"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ORDERLINETIMES/SUNDAY_OPEN"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ORDERLINETIMES/SUNDAY_CLOSE"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ENQUIRYLINETIMES/WEEKDAY_OPEN"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ENQUIRYLINETIMES/WEEKDAY_CLOSE"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ENQUIRYLINETIMES/SATURDAY_OPEN"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ENQUIRYLINETIMES/SATURDAY_CLOSE"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ENQUIRYLINETIMES/SUNDAY_OPEN"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ENQUIRYLINETIMES/SUNDAY_CLOSE"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="CORRESPONDENCE/NAME"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="CORRESPONDENCE/ADDRESS1"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="CORRESPONDENCE/ADDRESS2"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="CORRESPONDENCE/ADDRESS3"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="CORRESPONDENCE/ADDRESS4"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="CORRESPONDENCE/ADDRESS5"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="TRADING_AS_INDICATOR"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="REGISTERED_NUMBER"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="BRAND_LOGO_NUMBER"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            &comma;
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="FSA_TEXT"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output of csv file is coming as:**

JDW,A,,,"SBU","Simply Be Inquiries" , "Speciality Home Shopping (US) Limited" , "Griffin House" , "40 Lever Street" ,   "Manchester" , "United Kingdom" , "M60 6ES" , "www.simplybe.com" , "03941468" , "7" , "18774074675" , "18774074675" , "8am" , "11pm" , "8am" , "11pm" , "8am" , "11pm" , "8am" , "11pm" , "8am" , "11pm" , "8am" , "11pm" , "Simply Be Inquiries" , "777 South State Road 7" , "Margate, Florida 33068" , "" , "" , "" , "Y" , "03941468" , "DAL90" , **"""Simply Be" is a trading name of Speciality Home Shopping (US) Limited, registered in England with Co No. 03941468 and registered office at Griffin House, 40 Lever Street, Manchester UK M60 6ES""**

**but the required output is**

JDW,A,,,"SBU","Simply Be Inquiries" , "Speciality Home Shopping (US) Limited" , "Griffin House" , "40 Lever Street" ,   "Manchester" , "United Kingdom" , "M60 6ES" , "www.simplybe.com" , "03941468" , "7" , "18774074675" , "18774074675" , "8am" , "11pm" , "8am" , "11pm" , "8am" , "11pm" , "8am" , "11pm" , "8am" , "11pm" , "8am" , "11pm" , "Simply Be Inquiries" , "777 South State Road 7" , "Margate, Florida 33068" , "" , "" , "" , "Y" , "03941468" , "DAL90" , **"""Simply Be"" is a trading name of Speciality Home Shopping (US) Limited, registered in England with Co No. 03941468 and registered office at Griffin House, 40 Lever Street, Manchester UK M60 6ES"**

Comment: Please add your source XML and specify version of XSLT.

Comment: My xslt version is <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

Comment: I have edited the question and added the details

Comment: The version of XSLT is determined by the XSLT processor you are using, not by the `version` attribute on the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: I tried with <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/> .....i got 1.0

Comment: @MichaelKay: Could you please help.

Comment: @user2083356 It's over 10 years since I did anything with XSLT 1.0 and I don't find it much fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally you have a text in which you want to replace every instances of double quote " with two double quotes instead of one ""

Unfortunately XSLT 1.0 makes it ridiculously difficult to replace instances of a string with another.

You can do it with a recursive named template that takes a string as parameter, and will output this string with every " doubled as "". The recursive principle is,

- either the string contains no " and it is output as-is
- or it does contain a ", so you output everything before the first " as-is, then you output "", then you repeat the process on the string that's after the first ".

Example:

apply this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="doublequotes">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="quot">"</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $quot)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $quot)"/>
            <xsl:text>""</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="doublequotes">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $quot)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="input">
    <result>
        <xsl:call-template name="doublequotes"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to this:

```
<input>I want to shout "Hello world" out there!</input>
```

**Edit:** So, to apply that to your situation

keep the named template, and replace

```
<xsl:value-of select="FSA_TEXT">
```

with

```
<xsl:call-template name="doublequotes">
  <xsl:with-param name="text" select="FSA_TEXT"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, could you please help me to writing full xsl as per above example.

Comment: I have tried to apply path as below example in my xslt but it didnt got any output    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:template match="/TRADING_TITLE/TITLE">

Comment: @user2083356 I edited my answer to show how to use it in your case.